# What is the effect of having multiple buildscript blocks in a build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

Is it correct to have multiple buildscript blocks in a `build.gradle`?

If yes, how do these buildscript blocks interact with each other? For example, here is some code from a `build.gradle`,

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.1'
  }
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.5'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
```

For this piece of code, my questions are:

1. Which version of com.bmuschko.tomcat will be used?
2. What is the resulted `repositories`? mavenCentral(), jcenter() or both?

Comment: Have a look at this to understand how gradle works.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html

Comment: @Srikanth I have already read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies. But I can't find information related to my questions.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/issues/68